# How to sort strings with times by time in Java?

Tags: java

I have set of strings like

```
"12:00:10, some words here"
"12:10:32, some words here" 
"13:02:46, Some words here"
"12:39:12, some words here"
```

if the time is `hh:mm:ss` format, how do I sort these lines so that I get this output:

```
"12:00:10, some words here"
"12:10:32, some words here"
"12:39:12, some words here"
"12:39:12, some words here"
```

Comment: Java _or_ Javascript? Did you try anything yet? If so, what?

Comment: i am writing it in eclipse using java

Comment: If the timestamps are formatted in the same way (i.e. `07:08:09` instead of `7:8:9`) then sorting should not be a problem anyways.

Comment: `i am writing it in eclipse using java`- then what's the javascript tag for?

Comment: ok.. what have you tried so far...

Comment: This is a result set from a different logic. consider this as an output. I have set of strings as output and the first element is time. I have to sort that output in ascending order of time. How can i do that?

Comment: Ok, those are the results from whatever data you're obtaining from a datasource (database, `ResultSet`, web service, whatever). **What have you tried** to solve this?

Comment: I have no idea on collection sort

Comment: Suggestion: ask google for "java collections sort"

Answer (score 4):

Dont know what kind of data structure you are using, but a simple Arrays.sort will do , if you are using Arrays.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String[] str = new String[] { "12:00:10, some words here", "12:10:32, some words here",
                "13:02:46, Some words here", "12:39:12, some words here" };
        System.out.println("Before Sorting");
        for(String s:str)       {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        Arrays.sort(str);

        System.out.println("After Sorting");
        for(String s:str)       {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

Output

Before Sorting
12:00:10, some words here
12:10:32, some words here
13:02:46, Some words here
12:39:12, some words here
After Sorting
12:00:10, some words here
12:10:32, some words here
12:39:12, some words here
13:02:46, Some words here
```

Comment: Ah I totally over complicated things. Doing an Array.sort would've been so much simpler. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints to get you started:

1. In this case, I would use `Map` since the set of words are always divided into the timestamp, followed by the chosen word. Find a way to parse the strings so that you can store the timestamp as the key and the word as the value.
2. Take those timestamps and sort it with the highest priority being the hour and the lowest priority being the seconds. One way I would do this is to simply take out the colons and compare the `int` values of those timestamps. For example, in your case, it would be like:

   ```
   // Unsorted
   120010
   121032
   130246
   123912
   ```

   And if you were to sort this by their `int` values, it would look like the following:

   ```
   // Sorted
   120010
   121032
   123912
   130246
   ```

   Finding a sort for this would only take a few seconds as there are so many resources for this.
3. Lastly, since you know how it should be ordered, you can apply that logic into the `Map` that you made in the beginning. And you just have to print it out with the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **wrapper class** for your `String` value and implements the `Comparator` interface for it :

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item>
{

    String value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Item o)
    {
        return this.getNumericValue().compareTo(o.getNumericValue());
    }

    //Extract the numeric part from the string
    public Integer getNumericValue()
    {
        final String[] pair = this.value.split(",");
        return Integer.parseInt(pair[0].replace(":", ""));
    }

}
```

Then to sort your list simply use :

```
Collections.sort(list);
```